# Anchor tag helper not working in MVC 6 AND Angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a working new ASP.NET 5 project using MVC 6 and [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs).

My web page data binding are working as expected, but when I use an MVC 6 Anchor `TagHelper` in my project, data bindings are not working as expected.

```
 <div class="browse-movie-wrap col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:{IsPublished:true}">
```

**CSHTML:**

```
   {{ movie.Id }}  @*is working*@

<a asp-controller="Movie" asp-action="MovieDetail" asp-route-movieId="{{ movie.Id }}" class="browse-movie-link">
    @*this does not work*@
</div>
```

**Generated HTML:**

```
<div class="browse-movie-wrap col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:{IsPublished:true}">

228 //id is binded

<a class="browse-movie-link" href="/Movie/MovieDetail?movieId=%7B%7B%20movie.Id%20%7D%7D">

//but not binded anchor tag helper its remains movieID
```

**Note:** the code is in the same page

I've also open an issue in the MVC repository. You can find it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3789).

Comment: Your {{ is being encoded by asp. It would be better to generate this href entirely in angularJs. Using ng-href.

Comment: @yeouuu ,yes now looking forwad angular js.anyway thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you are doing.

You are sending [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) code to ASP.NET. Do you see the issue? You're telling ASP.NET:

> My movie ID is `{{ movie.Id }}`

So ASP.NET takes `{{ movie.Id }}` and encodes it into your URL.

You're using client-side code in a server side concept.

Comment: You are using client-side evaluated code on the server. You are using AngularJS concept in MVC6. It's like trying to fit a square block in a triangular hole. It's not going to work as-is.

Comment: Yes , I understand the situation

Comment: But when use ng-href I think I was hard coded like this controller/action/parm1={{id}}

Comment: It's worked,but what I expected  serverside execution  to tell its client code don't touch this,

Comment: Sorry for typos ,now iam sending my mobile device

Comment: ng-href is an angular js concept. {{ movie.Id }} is angular js. Angular will evaluate it and it will work. But then you use `asp-route-movieId` this is a 100% MVC 6 concept. Angular doesn't know about it. MVC 6 doesn't know you are giving it client side code. The attribute is explicitly named `asp-` because it's 100% MVC and not "real" client code. You will have to use C# code in that `asp-` attribute.

Comment: I get your point anyway thanks ,but my need is fully client side functional .so I remove tag helper and putting  angular URL builder options to overcome my solution